# How can I use the data the is return from the Ajax?

Tags: php, jquery, arrays

I am using ajax to retrieve data from my database and store it as an array, then I return the result. My goal is, when the users click the "Click Me" button. I want to alert the first array from the data that is returned. However, my code below is not returning anything.

```
<input type="button" id="click_me" value="Click Me"/>

var data_array;

$.post('generate.php', {id: id}, function(data){
                data_array= data;         
});

$('#click_me').click(function(){
   alert(data_array[0]);
});
```

generate.php

```
<?php
    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    $array = array('Hello', 'Good Morning', 'Nice to meet you');

    echo json_encode($array);

?>
```

Comment: You are posting at the moment the page loads -> not so smart! use `$(document).ready(function () { /*ajax call*/ });` and you have to put your javascript between `<script>/* js here*/</script>`. And why not do the post when button is clicked. Look at my answer please.

Answer (score 1):

Don't declare data-array as a local variable, use the global one by removing 'var' in nested success callback declaration:

```
$.post('generate.php', {id: id}, function(data){
                data_array= data;         
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It won't work this way since the ajax request is async. One thing that you could do is

```
 var data_array;

  $.post('generate.php', {id: id}, function(data){
      data_array= data; 
      $('#click_me').click(function(){
      alert(data_array[0]);
   });        
});
```

Or if you make sure that you are clicking the button only after the data is received your present code would work

A third option would be to retrieve the data when the user click the button

```
 $('#click_me').click(function(){
      $.post('generate.php', {id: id}, function(data){
       data_array= data; 
     alert(data_array[0]);        
   });

 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Well as I see you want to use json and Javascript. When sending json with mime type `application/json` Its automatically transferred to an array. this is because json is an respected data type and all major browsers support it.

This is my jquery/javascript:

```
                $(document).ready(function () { 
                    $('body').on('click', '#clickme', function(){
                        $.post('json.php', function (json){ 

                            // Now do stuff with the json
                            var table = ''; 
                            for(q = 0; q < $(json).size(); q++){
                                table += '<tr><td>' + json[q] + '</td></tr>';
                            }
                            var content = '<table>' +table+ '</table>';
                            $('#put_stuf_inside_me').html(content);

                        }); 
                    });
                });
```

my html:

```
<input type="button" id="clickme" value="do magic" />
<div id="put_stuf_inside_me"></div>
```

my php:

```
<?php

    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    $array = array('Hello', 'Good Morning','Nice to meet you','I put something over here');

    echo json_encode($array);

?>
```

You see how easy it is!